# Get only one comment per post with get_comments

Tags: comments

Is there a way to limit get_comments results to just the latest comment from every post?

Answer (score 1):

```
get_comments( array( 'number' => '1') );
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

Comment: Not one comment, but max one from each post

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you trying display one comment from all posts?

Comment: Show the most recent comment, ignore the others from that post, go on to show the next most recent comment from another post, ignore the others from that post and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $comments = get_comments(array( 'number' => 1, 'post_id' => get_the_ID() )); ?>
```

You'll have to specify the ID if you're not in loop

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

Comment: Same as above, I don't want just one comment but a bunch of them, with no more than one (the most recent) from each post.

Comment: Either you can use the above solution in a loop changing the `post_id` everytime or you'll have to customize the SQL query with `comments_clauses` filter

Comment: A loop seems like the way to go, I'll have to explore into that.